# ios accent letters appearing strange

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am parsing some JSON in my iOS app and setting some labels with the text. Some of the labels should appear like this:

`Beyoncé`

However, when shown in the label they appear as:

`BeyoncÃ©`

The font im using supports accents but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to display properly, even when using `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.

Any ideas?

Comment: What character do you see inside the debugger if you check what did you parse out?

Comment: Debugger returns same thing: `BeyoncÃ©`

Comment: Then it's probably inside the parser. Right? Where are you getting the data from?

Comment: Inside of JSON is: `Beyoncé` (direct paste)

Comment: A local server, I have complete control over both ends.

Comment: What do you use to parse it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your JSON have an encoding parameter, or can you get it from the response header? I do it like this using a `NSHTTPURLResponse`:

```
- (NSString *)decodedStringWithResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response data:(NSData *)data {
    NSStringEncoding encoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding;
    if (response.textEncodingName) {
        CFStringEncoding IANAEncoding = CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding((__bridge CFStringRef)response.textEncodingName);
        if (IANAEncoding != kCFStringEncodingInvalidId) {
            encoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(IANAEncoding);
        }
    }

    NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:encoding];
    if (!decodedString)
        decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if (!decodedString)
        decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
    if (!decodedString)
        decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSISOLatin2StringEncoding];

    return decodedString;
}
```

Comment: FYI this is missing a closing curly brace but even when added it complains of _Control may reach end of non-void function_.

Comment: formatting error on copy/paste fixed now, but you still get the gist of the solution, ie reading the encoding from the response

Comment: Yep! Giving it a shot

Comment: Looks like this might work, only thing is I need the JSON response in an `NSDictionary`, not an `NSString`. So, I'm working on that. Very new to objective-c...

Comment: Check out NSJSONSerialization or some of the open source json libraries out there

Comment: Yeah I'm using NSJSONSerialization but I'm trying to figure out where to pipe in the encoding bit.

Comment: Hm, I can't seem to get it to cooperate. Any quick ideas?

Comment: So the encoding returned by the server, and read from the header in the above method is UTF8?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44012/discussion-between-masedesign-and-coneybeare)

Comment: Yikes! I was using `NSASCIIStringEncoding` somewhere further up the pipeline and that's what caused this. Sorry for the run around!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're currently using to parse this but you should give SBJSON a shot. It's super easy to use and here's a tutorial that'll save you lots of trouble probably:

http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309924609/how-to-use-json-in-cocoaobjective-c

SBJSON: https://github.com/stig/json-framework